# Meaning of <bytecode: #> in R's built-in function definitions

Tags: r

What does `<bytecode: 0x02b59ae4>` in below code mean ?

```
> nchar
function (x, type = "chars", allowNA = FALSE, keepNA = FALSE) 
.Internal(nchar(x, type, allowNA, keepNA))
<bytecode: 0x02b59ae4>
<environment: namespace:base>`
```

is it useful for anything ?

Comment: It's just the memory address of the bitcode.

Comment: ok, so it is useful for anything ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `bytecode` statement indicates that the function has been byte compiled by the `compiler` package. All base R functions are byte compiled. Byte compiled functions are almost always faster than the non-compiled version.

If a package has a `ByteCompile: true` in its DESCRIPTION file, all functions in the package will be byte-compiled.

You can compile your own functions if you want:

```
f = function(x) x
f_cmp = compiler::cmpfun(f)
f
# function(x) x
f_cmp
# function(x) x
# <bytecode: 0x7f371a8>
```

Alternatively, you can set `R_COMPILE_PKGS=3` in your `.Renviron` and that will byte-compile package on installation. This assumes you are installing the package from source.

Comment: What about address given by byte code is it useful at all?